# What does the ng stand for in Angular.js directives

Tags: angularjs

Angular.js uses several directives prefixed with `ng` like below:

`ng` (base directive)

```
ng-switch
ng-repeat
ng-view
```

I was wondering if anyone knew what `ng` stood for because I couldn't find it in the docs. Is it an acronym for something?

Comment: I say forget it even exists and use the standards compliant data-prefix instead.

Comment: @ACJ Hmm... I thought that *ng* **was** the default prefix in AngularJS. What should be used instead, according to your experience?

Comment: @KonradViltersten, the `ng-` prefix **is** the default. However, the `data-` prefix is a more standards-compliant way to achieve the same result. If you’re concerned with mixing up Angular related stuff with plain old HTML, you can of course also use a `data-ng-` prefix. That’s perfectly valid.

Comment: Does it have any connection with [*Andrew Ng*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_Ng)?

Comment: Long before the framework was introduced, I heard of NG from watching a lot of Hong Kong flix on DVD; they often contained a bunch of "N.G. Scenes" or "No-Good scenes":  Deleted scenes.  I even saw a movie where a character shouted "N.G.! N.G.!" in the context of "This doesn't count!"  Now whenever I work on an Angular project I usually read the ng-codes as "no-good-whatever" or sometimes, if NG is followed by a vowel, as if it were a Cantonese word, like "ngo."

Answer (score 296, accepted):

The prefix `ng` stands for "Angular;" all of the built-in directives that ship with Angular use that prefix. Similarly, it is recommended that you *do not* use the `ng` prefix on your *own* directives in order to avoid possible name collisions in future versions of Angular.

From [the FAQ](http://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq):

> **Why is this project called "AngularJS"? Why is the namespace called "ng"?**
>
> Because HTML has Angular brackets and "ng" sounds like "Angular".

Comment: "ng" definitely does not sound like "Angular".

Comment: "ng" sounds like "Angular" the same way "mkdir" sounds like "make directory".  As in old Hebrew, vowels are irrelevant. :-)

Comment: @Backwards_Dave and that's pretty much one of those things that pissed me off it. Efforts should be made to make codes fun to do!!

Comment: @Charles Roth "ng" does not sound like "Angular" in this context because I want to believe that when you pronounce "mkdir", you'll usually go like "make directory" as you rightly put it; but I bet when you want to pronounce something like "ng-view", common folks will usually go like "EN-GEE-VIEW"... That doesn't sound like "Angular" to me  -\\_0_/-

Comment: @CharlesRoth with your logic it should actually be nglr which sounds much more like Angular than ng does.

Comment: Y'all are thinking about this way too much :P

Comment: Now it makes much more sense to me, why the framework is called Angular and what ng stands for. It has no usefulness, but still a fun fact to learn)

Comment: Then again, "ng" pronounced as "enn gee" sounds like "Angie", which seems like a pet name of Angular.

Comment: After Windows NT (new technology), Windows 2000 used to say "Built on NT Technology" which stood for "Built on New Technology Technology"

Comment: I tend to pronounce it like the Cantonese consonant Ng, especially if it's followed by a vowel like "ngif" which I read as one syllable.  But usually, since I've watched a heap of Hong Kong movies on discs that come with "N(o)G(ood) scenes," and I don't feel at all fond of this clusterf--- of a framework, I'll read Angular's NG as "no-good."

Answer (score 46):

I guess there are not many Star Trek fans among you. "ng" stands for *Next Generation*, as Angular is the next generation of `HTML`.

"Enhanced" `HTML` I would say xD.

Comment: It doesn't stand for Newgrounds?

Comment: I really want this to be true.

Comment: I thought it was "Nyuk Gnyuk!", named by some wiseguy.

Answer (score 36):

I thought they took an arbitrary subsection of the Angular name and used it as the name space:

a**NG**ular

Plus "NG" does not sound like Angular; no matter which way you say it.

Comment: It is not that `NG` sounds like Angular. Of course, `NG` sounds like `ngee`. But we don't have to compare the pronunciations of `NG` with the full word `Angular`. `NG` is more of an abbreviation. So even if we drop the first `A` and try to pronounce `Ngular` it'll still sound like Angular only. So they took the starting fragment `NG` of the word `Ngular` to create an abbreviation which is used a prefix.

Answer (score 12):

`ng` is an abbreviation of A**ng**ular.

Programmers don't like to code long names, so they keep it short and that makes it a bit more cryptic. If you look at Assembler, you know what I mean with ADD, JMP etc. JQuery is the name, the `$` is what you use. Angular is the name, `ng` is what you use.

Comment: Which is wonderful for cli use if tab autocomplete isn't working well

Answer (score 6):

NG stands for "**Next Generation**".

It is used in many applications as a suffix, specially in **Linux**. Example: syslog-ng and Aircrack-ng.

Comment: Doesn't the ng in the case of aircrack stand for "engine"?

Comment: Do you have documentation to support that this is relevant to Angular? Otherwise, I'm not sure this addresses the OP.

Comment: Angular 1 was not next generation. It was Just crap by design.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [AngularJS Miscellaneous FAQ](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq#why-is-this-project-called-angularjs-why-is-the-namespace-called-ng-):

**Why is this project called "AngularJS"? Why is the namespace called "ng"?**
Because HTML has Angular brackets and "ng" sounds like "Angular".

Comment: From Moe's post below, I agree ""NG" does not sound like Angular; no matter which way you say it.". This is from their own FAQ. =)

Comment: I find it hilarious that they think "ng" sounds like "angular". Angular has 3 syllables for goodness sake.

Comment: And people keep shouting, "It's an abbreviation!"  Abbreviations usually don't omit the first letter as doing so exacerbates the obscurity.

Answer (score 1):

This guy is a Google superstar, I think ng is a part of their culture.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_Ng

Comment: There are no super stars working at Google. Just very very very Lucky Guys.

Comment: I have a theory that a lot of people love Angular so much only because using it makes them feel like they're a part of the O Great Google.